# How to get these array values using foreach?

Tags: php, yii

```
Array (
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => priyaa
        [1] => aarthy
    )
    [10] => Array (
        [0] => testa
        [1] => test member 1
    )
)
```

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a loop inside a loop if you are unsure how many results you will have.

For instance...

```
$YourArray = array();
//Add to array here.

foreach($YourArray as $LevelOne):
  foreach ($LevelOne as $LevelTwo):
   echo $LevelTwo . ' - ';
  endforeach;
  echo '<br>';
endforeach;
```

Would output for you.

```
priyaa - aarthy
testa - test member 1
```

Comment: I want output as Priya => Aarthy ANd Testa => Test member

Comment: See amended answer, this should do it for you.

Comment: This answer is usefull .. but from the above question there are two arrays inside an array.. but  I dont know how many arrays included in a single array .. then how to get ?

Comment: This will get every line in `$YourArray` and then if that contains any arrays (`$LevelOne`)will open up all them (calling them `$LevelTwo`). So 2 deep. It will go through all in the loop.

Comment: its very useful thanku

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it solve your problem

```
$array = array (
4 => array ( 
        0 => "priyaa"
        1 => "aarthy"
)
10 => array (
        0 => "testa"
        1 => "test member 1"
    )
);

foreach($array as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Cheers!